# UILocalNotification custom soundName only vibrates phone when alertBody is specified (unlike UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName)?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a VoIP app that uses a UILocalNotification to notify the user of an incoming call when the app is in the background. When a notification is presented I would like it to play a sound & vibrate the phone -- more than once (and without presenting the same message repeatedly). I was able to do this by using a series of notifications  - the first would immediately present the message and play a sound (the phone would vibrate as well) - following notifications were scheduled 3 seconds apart; they do not have an alertBody and alertAction but do have the same soundname as used in the first notification. HERE IS MY PROBLEM.. if a soundName other than the UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName is specified the phone will only vibrate for the first notification (the sound will be played each time though). However, if the default soundName is used, then the phone will vibrate with each notification? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another way.. display local notification and then start repeating the vibration via a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Sounds like a bug. [File it with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) and you might be able to get them to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks Noah.. but somehow Skype does it?