# Create custom sounds and vibrations in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, ios5

I've been trying to find information on how you can create custom vibrations in iOS.

Vibrations are easy enough when the application is active. But I want to play a custom vibration (like double vibration) together with a local notification when the application is in the background.

The sound framework only seem to give me sound handle ids while the UILocalNotification wants a sound file name.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the vibration on your own with a timer after you posted your local notification. See also [UILocalNotification custom soundName only vibrates phone when alertBody is specified (unlike UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112058/uilocalnotification-custom-soundname-only-vibrates-phone-when-alertbody-is-speci)

Comment: Well, the proposed solution is exactly the problem: you can not play vibration sounds with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` when the application is in the background. And `UILocalNotification` takes a `NSString` ring tone file name, not  a `SystemSoundID`. So my question is how to create a custom vibration sound file with only vibrations and no sound.